# Using react 15 in piral

Tags: reactjs, typescript, piral

I have an application in production using React 15 which can't be upgraded to the latest React (16) anytime soon.

For the future I want to use piral as a whole, but piral requires React 16 and I don't see how to use React 15 in a pilet.

How can React 15 be used in a pilet / with piral?

What I was thinking so far: I could just follow the path of piral-preact and include a converter. But I have trouble with this approach. Any recommendation or help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you could bundle React 15 / React 15 DOM in a pilet. If multiple pilets are used, you can make React 15 / React 15 DOM a shared dependency. For convenience a converter (e.g., like the one for [Inferno](https://github.com/smapiot/piral/tree/develop/src/packages/piral-inferno)) could be created.

Important: To avoid any collisions with the existing `react` and `react-dom` packages aliases should be used.

In the *package.json* these aliases can be specified like:

```
{
  // ...
  "dependencies": {
    "react-15": "npm:react@^15",
    "react-dom-15": "npm:react-dom@^15"
  }
}
```

Importing / using them also works with the alias then (e.g., `react-15`).

We are right now working on a React 15 converter that you could use out of the box. The current WIP can be seen [on the GitHub monorepo](https://github.com/smapiot/piral/tree/develop/src/converters/piral-react-15).

Comment: Defunc URL - https://github.com/smapiot/piral/tree/develop/src/packages/piral-react-15

Comment: Thanks @amar - corrected the URL to https://github.com/smapiot/piral/tree/develop/src/converters/piral-react-15